# I am trying to print from an array. But it loops infinitely

Tags: java, arrays, loops, printing, infinite

My ask is to make word pairs out of every single word in a textfile (typical schoolwork...) and then print out every wordpair that starts with the word "alice". This is my final task for this program, but now I am quite stuck at one point. I manage to print out alot of words. However, it loops infinitely and prints until I cancel the program. I have seen myself blind on this code, and could really use some help or tips as to how I could avoid it.

The code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class Oblig3C{
    public static void main(String[]args){

    OrdAnalyse oa = new OrdAnalyse();
    String filArgs=args[0];
    oa.analyseMetode(filArgs);
    }
}

class OrdAnalyse{
    void analyseMetode(String filArgs){

    //Begynner med aa opprette alle variabler som trengs, disse deklareres rett under. De ligger her oppe bare for at jeg skal ha oversikten over de.
    Scanner input, innfil;
    String[] ord;
    int[] antall;
    int antUnikeOrd, antOrd;
    PrintWriter utfil;
    boolean sjekk;

    //Deklarerer alle bortsett fra de som har med fil aa gjore, disse deklareres inne i en try-catch-loop (printwriter utfil og scanner innfil).
    input=new Scanner(System.in);
    ord=new String[5000];
    antall=new int[5000];
    antUnikeOrd=0;
    antOrd=0;
    sjekk=true;

    try{
        innfil=new Scanner(new File(filArgs));
        //Naa sjekker programmet om ordet som blir lest med Scanner-metoden er lest for. Er det slik, saa oeker den antallet i samme index i antall-arrayen med 1, den boolske verdien sjekk blir true, og neste if-lokke vil ikke kjore, for loopen er ferdig og neste ord leses.

        while(innfil.hasNext()){
        String ordLest=innfil.next().toLowerCase(); 
        sjekk=false;
            for(int i=0; i<ord.length; i++){
            if(ordLest.equals(ord[i])){
            antall[i]+=1;
            sjekk=true;
            }
        }
        if(!sjekk){
            //Her vil lokken oke telleren antUnikeOrd med en for hvert unike ord som leses, og denne er alltid en
            ord[antUnikeOrd]=ordLest;
            antall[antUnikeOrd]++;
            antUnikeOrd++;
        }

        antOrd++;
        }
        innfil.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    try{
        utfil=new PrintWriter(new File("Oppsummering.txt"));

        utfil.println("Antall ord lest: " +antOrd+ " og antall unike ord: "+antUnikeOrd);

        finnOrd(antall, ord, utfil);

        for(int i=0; i<ord.length; i++){
        utfil.println(ord[i]+("  ")+antall[i]);
        }

        utfil.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //Deklarerer metoden som skal brukes i c:
    try{
        innfil=new Scanner(new File(filArgs));
        ordParInn(innfil, antOrd, antUnikeOrd, ord);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }


    //Denne metoden er i bunn og grunn hele B-oppgaven.
    void finnOrd(int[] antall, String[] ord, PrintWriter utfil){
    int teller=1000;
    for(int i=0; i<ord.length; i++){
        if(antall[i]>teller){
        teller=antall[i];
        }
    }
    //Naa er teller lik den hoyeste verdien i antall-arrayen.

    //For aa faa mellomrom mellom innskrivingene, for ordens skyld.

    double tiprosent=teller*10/100;
    for(int i=0; i<ord.length; i++){
        if(antall[i]>tiprosent){
        utfil.println("Vanlige ord: "+ord[i]+"\t("+antall[i]+" forekomster)");
        }
    }
    }
```

Breaking off here. Because below this is the method where the problem is.

```
    //Denne metoden er C-oppgaven.
    void ordParInn(Scanner innfil, int antOrd, int antUnikeOrd, String[] ord){
    int [][] ordParTelling=new int[5000][5000];
    int sc1,sc2;
    String forrigeOrd=" ";
    sc1=0;
    sc2=0;

    while(innfil.hasNext()){
        String ordLest=innfil.next().toLowerCase();

        for(int i=0; i<ord.length; i++){
        if(!forrigeOrd.equals(" ")){
            sc1=Arrays.asList(ord).indexOf(ordLest);
            sc2=Arrays.asList(ord).indexOf(forrigeOrd);

            if(sc1>0 && sc2>0){
            ordParTelling[sc2][sc1]++;
            }
        }
        forrigeOrd=ordLest;
        } 

        int alice=Arrays.asList(ord).indexOf("alice");
        for(int i=0; i<antUnikeOrd; i++){
        if(ordParTelling[alice][i]>0){
            System.out.print(ordParTelling[alice][i]);
            System.out.print("    " + ord[i] + "    " + Arrays.asList(ord).indexOf(antUnikeOrd));
        }
        }
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should cut that down to the relevant parts, and post a stack trace

Comment: You need to call `.toString()` on your array when you are trying to print it.  Also, should you be using `System.out.println`?

Comment: The .toString was meant for the ord[i] at the bottom, right? Thanks Brian. It kinda showed me a little what is happening. It prints Alice, and then every word that it is paired with, but it does this infinitely many times. Any thoughts?